# only 1 thread possible with boost asio on machines with many cores

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, asynchronous, boost-asio

We have very weird problem, we manage to create very small somehow reproducible(on some PCs) example:
[main.cpp](https://pastebin.com/vBf11LS1) [Dockerfile](https://pastebin.com/z98J1ajF)
This code do absolutely nothing useful it only logs few lines, but these few lines prove it do not work with more than 1 thread.

**We use boost 1.70 (Asio 1.14.0)**

I tested on 3 computes so far:

### my desktop Ryzen 1950X 64 GB RAM mostly end up with:

```
started for 1 threads
Listener started on thread: 140593064609536
started for 2 threads
started for 3 threads
started for 4 threads
started for 5 threads
started for 6 threads
started for 7 threads
```

(sometimes 2, or 3 also works, but mostly not)
I tested on this machine also build with msvc on Windows and result was that it run fine, so the problem is somehow linux+core count specific.

### main server 2x E5-2630 v3 128 GB RAM mostly end up with:

```
root@cf8c892390ce:/app/test/bin# ./test
started for 1 threads
Listener started on thread: 140062574507776
started for 2 threads
started for 3 threads
started for 4 threads
started for 5 threads
started for 6 threads
started for 7 threads
```

(once in over 100 tests 2 also worked, but never more)

### old test server 2x old intel 2 core CPU 4 GB RAM most results look like this:

```
root@f06821a4cbc8:/app/test/bin# ./test
started for 1 threads
Listener started on thread: 140650646316800
started for 2 threads
Listener started on thread: 140650621138688
started for 3 threads
Listener started on thread: 140650246829824
started for 4 threads
Listener started on thread: 140650213259008
started for 5 threads
Listener started on thread: 140649944823552
started for 6 threads
Listener started on thread: 140649743496960
started for 7 threads
Listener started on thread: 140649726711552
```

(sometimes 5, 6, or 7 threads do not work)

We tested on few other systems and only 1 thread works reliably.

Can you please look at the code and tell me if we have some stupid mistake there?, or if this is bug in asio?

And most importantly can we fix it somehow?

Comment: Note that you don't provide any work for the `io_service`, so `run()` exits immediately. You try to re-run it, but do not call `restart()`, as required by asio [reference](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_context/restart.html).

Comment: Ah  @IgorR just my suspicion. Bit swamped so I'll just let you answer instead :) (got sidetracked installing boost 1.70)

Comment: @sehe no, you've already answered that :). Besides, there may be more issues in this code....

Comment: I wish I could accept comment, (yes there was another issue the lack of work).

Comment: I did not think about race condition, because `run()` is meant to be run on multiple threads, and there was nothing expect logs after I minimize it to this "reproducible" example, and `std::cout` can not cause any damage

Comment: It's ok to call `run` from another thread. The "race" here is like this: whether thread1 has time to add some work to the `io_service` before thread2 leaves `run` function, or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably start the event loops (run() and related) before the actual work is posted.

This would allow the services to complete before your listener is started (a race condition), and that explains the symptoms.

The usual way to avoid this is to use a `work<>` object.

Having a look at your code now.